# Latency Between Apache And Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, tomcat8

We have a setup where we have a Elastic LB that spreads load over two Apache servers A1 and A2. These apache servers render a few php pages and primarily redirects the API requests to tomcat appplication servers T1 and T2 as per the following diagram:

```
Incoming Request
    |
    |
    |
    \/
    LB
    /\
   /  \
  /    \
A1     A2
|\     /|
| \   / |
|  \ /  |
|  / \  |
T1      T2
```

We have recently started to note delays between apache and tomcat. Here is an example log lines from apache mod_slow log and tomcat access log for the same request:

```
APACHE_MOD_SLOW: VNSdtwoAAJkAACnXb-cAAACJ [06/Feb/2015:16:25:51 +0530] elapsed: 50.58 cpu: 0.00(usr)/0.00(sys) pid: 10711 ip: 10.0.0.153 host: www.example.com:443 reqinfo: GET /data/v1/url?url=test-508324 HTTP/1.1

TOMCAT: [06/Feb/2015:16:26:42 +0530] "GET /data/v1/url?url=test-508324 HTTP/1.1" 200 65 10
```

Apache says the incoming request came at `06/Feb/2015:16:25:51 +0530` and it took `50s` to process the request. Whereas tomcat says it took only `10ms` to process the request whereas it received the request at `06/Feb/2015:16:26:42 +0530`.

It means it took nearly 50s for apache to connect and send the whole request to tomcat. Apache is using `mod_proxy_ajp` to connect to apache.   Here is the configuration:

```
<Proxy balancer://prod>
   BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:8009 route=jvmRoute-8009 connectiontimeout=1 retry=300
   BalancerMember ajp://10.0.0.153:8009 route=jvmRoute-8009 connectiontimeout=1 retry=300    
   ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
```

Here is the connector configuration from tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="4096" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"/>
```

As per connectiontimeout value, I am assuming apache shouldn't take more than 1 sec to establish connection. Since both apache and tomcat are both on the same machine, there shouldn't be much time lag once connection is established.

If it helps, we are using `https` requests. But that, I don'y think has anything to do with this. We have done `ab` test in order to compare performance using `https`, `http` and connecting tomcat directly. Here are the stats:

```
ab -n5000 -c5 https://example.com/test/100001                                        

Requests per second:    13.67 [#/sec] (mean)                                        
Time per request:       365.851 [ms] (mean)                                        
Time per request:       73.170 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)                                        
Transfer rate:          79.96 [Kbytes/sec] received                                        

Connection Times (ms)                                        
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max                                        
Connect:      236  267  95.5    247    3401                                        
Processing:    83   98  58.6     89    1959                                        
Waiting:       82   96  57.5     87    1959                                        
Total:        319  365 134.0    338    3571                                        

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)                                        
  50%    338                                        
  66%    347                                        
  75%    356                                        
  80%    364                                        
  90%    399                                        
  95%    477                                        
  98%    689                                        
  99%    869                                        
 100%   3571 (longest request)

ab -n5000 -c5 http://example.com/test/100001                                        

Time per request:       186.015 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       37.203 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          155.55 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       74   79  33.4     76    1278
Processing:    83  107  82.3     91    3964
Waiting:       82  105  60.9     89     940
Total:        157  186  90.1    168    4042

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    168
  66%    174
  75%    180
  80%    184
  90%    211
  95%    259
  98%    379
  99%    507
 100%   4042 (longest request)

ab -n5000 -c5 http://IP:8080/test/100001                                        

Requests per second:    31.32 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       159.624 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       31.925 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          181.30 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       71   76  68.4     73    3079
Processing:    78   84  13.1     81     594
Waiting:       77   83   6.5     81     185
Total:        149  159  71.2    154    3313

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    154
  66%    157
  75%    160
  80%    161
  90%    166
  95%    171
  98%    177
  99%    189
 100%   3313 (longest request)
```

Following observation leads me to believe this that bad performance is depending on sequence of events because none of the requests in the test performed that badly.

Versions:
    Apache: 2.2.4
    Tomcat: 8.0.16

Any ideas where the lag is coming from and how to reduce the  same?

Comment: Usually this sort of delay is indicative of the reponse having an invalid content length and the user agent (httpd in this case) waiting for the rest of the response it is expecting before eventually timing out the connection. Check your response headers and use -k with ab to use keep-alive as that is more likely to trigger an issue of this type.

Comment: @mark: This may not be the case with us because tomcat has eventually served the request with 200 status code

Comment: Assuming there is keep alive between Apache and tomcat and lb and Apache. If not check netstat .

Comment: @Khanna111GauravKhanna: keep alive is in place

Comment: DNS / inverse-DNS issues somewhere? I think tcpdump or wireshark can provide lot of info. Or even netstat. You can use something like:

    watch -n 1 "netstat -ntp | grep 8009"

to monitor what's going on with connections.

Comment: In my experience response times that are clustered around 10, 25 and 50 seconds are almost always thread pool starvation. You can add the response time to tomcat (see here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html). If that shows up as (in this case) 58 msecs then I would bet that the tomcat servlet thread pool is full and that request got parked for 50 seconds